# Can't install rails - "File exists @ dir_s_mkdir" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsapps, learn-ruby-on-rails

I have had rails installed and almost working.  Was working on a solution to another problem with I accidentally closed the bash window.  So I reopened it, and now I am unable to use rails at all and it's telling me that rails isn't installed.  So I ran `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc`and now I get the following:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EEXIST)
File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.1_1/lib/ruby/gems`
```

How do I correct this error?

Comment: it's the same here ;) also with homebrew on a mac?

Comment: Yep.  Mac and Homebrew

Comment: Filed a bug to fix this in the homebrew formula: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022489/cant-install-rails-file-exists-dir-s-mkdir-error

Answer (score 7):

I just removed the broken `gems`, `site_ruby` and `vendor_ruby` symlinks from the `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.1_1/lib/ruby/` folder and now everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just added a gems/ directory here /usr/local/lib/ruby/ and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

for a temporary solution, you can `mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.1_1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0` to solve.

Answer (score 0):

When you open your bash window (called the "terminal window" or "console"), what folder ("directory") are you in? Find out with:

```
$ pwd
```

Navigate to the folder where you created your Rails project using the Unix cd command, for example:

```
$ cd workspace/learn-rails
```

If you are using RVM, make sure you have selected the correct gemset:

```
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.1.1 (found in ...)
   (default)
   global
=> learn-rails
```

Then see if Ruby and Rails are installed:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.0
```

Refer to the article [Install Ruby on Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) for help. If you haven't followed all the steps in the article, you may have problems, especially if you followed some of the inaccurate instructions found elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently in this wormhole.  It seems like Homebrew's ruby installation has an issue with soft links and uses version 2.1.1.  I couldn't "gem install" anything without getting the annoying "File exists @ dir_s_mkdir" error.  Even tried MacPort and that was a nightmare.

First uninstall ruby via

```
brew uninstall ruby
```

or

```
port uninstall ruby
```

And follow the instruction on https://rvm.io/rvm/install to install ruby

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

It might then complain about ruby-2.0.0-p353 not installed

To install do:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353
```

Then run the rvm install script.  Your "gem install << whatever >>" should now work

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me (Homebrew on a Mac, Ruby 2.1.3):

`$ brew reinstall ruby
$ brew unlink ruby && brew link ruby`

Answer (score 0):

the same issue. I just remove dir_s_mkdir, then pod install. it works for me!